# Fixing an equation numbering issue

Tags: equations, numbering, equation-number

I'm writing a paper with multiple authors and I'm having trouble fixing an equation numbering issue.

The desire was for equations to be numbered within subsections. At the same time, the goal was for all numberings to be unique, and so Lemma 2.2.3 would be followed by equation 2.2.4 and subsection 2.2.5. Whatever the motivations, the result is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\newtheorem{theorem}[subsubsection]{Theorem}
\def\numequation{\addtocounter{subsubsection}{1}\begin{equation}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}

We have
\begin{equation} \label{one} 1+1 \ge 2 \end{equation}
and also
\numequation \label{two} 1+1 \le 2 \end{equation}
similar to Equation~(\ref{one}). 
We wish to have:
\begin{equation} \label{three} 1+1 \ge 2 \end{equation}
\begin{theorem} $1+1=2$.
\end{theorem}
Proof: Equations~(\ref{one}) and~(\ref{two}) imply equation~(\ref{three}).


\end{document}
```

This compiles with no errors, but the equations are numbered (0.0.0), (0.0.1),  and then equation (0.0.1), whereas the last equation should be numbered (0.0.2), and then the Theorem should be (0.0.3).  (I guess (0.0.1)-(0.0.4) would be better.)

This paper is several hundred pages with multiple uses of \begin{equation} and \numequation. Moreover the paper is in the proof stage, so I would really desire a solution which can be done with as few changes as possible.

> Question: Is there a simple fix to the preamble which will correct the numbering issue? Note that we are using a custom style file for the relevant journal.

I had hoped that changing the preamble to

```
\def\numequation{\begin{equation}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\addtocounter{subsubsection}{1}\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
```

would fix things, but now the equations are labelled (0.0.1), (0.0.2), and (0.0.4) --- somehow the reference is adding one to the numbering.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Try replacing `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsection}}` with `\counterwithin{equation}{subsubsection}`. And, please replace `\addtocounter{subsubsection}{1}` with `\refstepcounter{subsubsection}`.

Comment: @Mico This fixes some issues but is no longer compatible with Theorem numbering: equations (0.0.1)-(0.0.3) are now followed by Theorem (0.0.2) not Theorem (0.0.4).

Comment: Ah but maybe \newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Theorem} then works...

Comment: Since you are using `amsart`, the facilities of `amsthm` apply.  Sharing theorem and equation numbers is mentioned in the `amsthm` user guide through a pointer to this FAQ entry: http://www.ams.org/faq?faq_id=289 which does identify using `[equation]` as the shared numbering for theorems.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Actually the style file is not amsart but rather some custom style file for another journal

Comment: @Confused -- Ah, your example is misleading.  But as long as `amsthm` is being used, the suggestion to use `[equation]` is supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that with what you already have, the easiest thing to do is just to make the `equation` environment step the `subsubsection` counter.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\newtheorem{theorem}[subsubsection]{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\stepcounter{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}

We have
\begin{equation} \label{one} 1+1 \ge 2 \end{equation}
and also
\begin{equation} \label{two} 1+1 \le 2 \end{equation}
similar to Equation~(\ref{one}). 
We wish to have:
\begin{equation} \label{three} 1+1 \ge 2 \end{equation}
\begin{theorem} $1+1=2$.
\end{theorem}
Proof: Equations~(\ref{one}) and~(\ref{two}) imply equation~(\ref{three}).

\end{document}
```

In the above I removed the `\numequation` command since it was not really needed, but if you want to keep it because of the code you already have, you could just use

```
\newcommand*{\numequation}{\begin{equation}}
```

so that it does not influence the counters.

Comment: As smooth as butter, thanks.

Comment: +1. You could further simplify the code by replacing `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}` with `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesubsubsection}`.